# How can I make gnubg work with Tavla backgammon rules?

Tags: c

Is it possible to somehow make [gnubg](https://www.gnu.org/s/gnubg/) work with tavla rules?
(Tavla is the Turkish name for backgammon. https://www.bkgm.com/variants/Tavla.html)

The rules are as follows:

> There is no "hit-and-run" in the player's home board.
>
> A checker sitting alone on a point is called a blot. If an opposing checker lands on a blot, the blot is hit and placed on the bar.
>
> You may not run for cover after hitting an opposing blot in your own home board. If you choose to hit within your home board, you must cover the hitting checker with another of your own checkers or leave it exposed.

I tried to:

- find and enable such rule in gnubg GUI but with no luck.
- read sources of `gnubg` for understand if I can insert that rule and make a custom build. I found something in `eval.c:1039` but don't fully understand the code. https://github.com/mormegil-cz/gnubg/blob/master/eval.c#L1039

```
    /* for every point we'd consider hitting a blot on, */

    for (i = (nBoard > 2) ? 23 : 21; i >= 0; i--)
        /* if there's a blot there, then */

        if (anBoardOpp[i] == 1)
            /* for every point beyond */

            for (j = 24 - i; j < 25; j++)
                /* if we have a hitter and are willing to hit */

                if (anBoard[j] && !(j < 6 && anBoard[j] == 2))
                    /* for every roll that can hit from that point */

                    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
                        if (aanCombination[j - 24 + i][n] == -1)
                            break;

                        /* find the intermediate points required to play */

                        pi = aIntermediate + aanCombination[j - 24 + i][n];

                        if (pi->fAll) {
                            /* if nFaces is 1, there are no intermediate points */

                            if (pi->nFaces > 1) {
                                /* all the intermediate points are required */

                                for (k = 0; k < 3 && pi->anIntermediate[k] > 0; k++)
                                    if (anBoardOpp[i - pi->anIntermediate[k]] > 1)
                                        /* point is blocked; look for other hits */
                                        goto cannot_hit;
                            }
                        } else {
                            /* either of two points are required */

                            if (anBoardOpp[i - pi->anIntermediate[0]] > 1 && anBoardOpp[i - pi->anIntermediate[1]] > 1) {
                                /* both are blocked; look for other hits */
                                goto cannot_hit;
                            }
                        }

                        /* enter this shot as available */

                        aHit[aanCombination[j - 24 + i][n]] |= 1 << j;
                      cannot_hit:;
                    }
```

Comment: This question is too broad, you'll have to ask about a specific part of some code which you don't understand. Post the code here on this site. If the whole file is huge and there are multiple things you don't understand, ask several different questions.

Comment: @Lundin I put the code here. Also I've made a feature request  in https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-gnubg
but they declined it.
So the only option is to understand the code and make changes.

Comment: Well it looks like a school book example of bad practices in C. Cryptic for loops, deeply nested compound statements, spaghetti programming with goto, excessive use of magic numbers. It would probably be a better idea to leave this code at the **ithub junkyard and rewrite the program from scratch. If you still want to dig deep into this slop, then at a minimum you'll have to post the variable declarations as well... and don't assume that every programmer knows the rules of backgammon (or are willing to learn them just to answer this question).